# TWRP loop on booting nokia 3?

Tags: twrp, boot-loop, nokia-3

i successfully installed twrp but on twrp reboot i selected system and now on opening nokia 3 it goes to twrp.
Only twrp can be opened not the OS (normal boot) of nokia 3.

I tried flashing stock rom of nokia 3 with sp flash tools but on starting or booting phone , it will not detect nokia 3 and red and yellow bars does not appear.
so how to flash stock firmware when i am stuck boot looping in to Twrp.
Any other way if possible please describe.

Answer (score 0):

As your question you install twrp recovery and did you perform wipe after that ? If not try this might work or try the following

1. Turn power of your phone in twrp recovery option by reboot\power off or hold the power button till it shuts down.
2. Now load stock rom in sp flash tool.
3. Now click on download button.
4. it will dectect your phone if your phone is power off and if battery is removable please remove it before connecting
5. now connect your phone with usb in one end and to other end with pc.
6. if it didn't dectect install the right mtk drivers.
7. after successful install your phone turns to stock os with stock recovery and will boot normally.

Alternative

1. Find custom os for your device.
2. move it to sd card.
3. flash it through twrp recovery.
4. then perform wipe and clean cache and boot normally.

Hope it works.

Comment: in twrp i clicked on reboot =>system and after reboot it shows android logo with orange state and then goes to twrp again .                    On trying to flash stock rom and clicking download nothing happens no red bar or yellow bar which gives tick pop up.               when will sp flash tool shows red or yellow bar.

Comment: Click on reboot/power of instead of reboot/system because your rom might be having problem after flashing wrong twrp recovery or your bootloader is not unlock.

Comment: You can just copy recovery.img from stock rom and past it to sd card and flash it with twrp recovery and it will overwrite it then you will get your stock recovery back and just perform wipe,reset with that recovery and it will work fine.

Comment: bootloader is unlocked thats why it is showing orange state and i have three options in twrp when rebooting.                         1) system 2) recovery 3) fastboot mode   and on system and recovery rebooting only TWRP appears that means    phone is not booting normally and it goes to twrp instead.And i amtrying to flash with spflash tool but spflash tool does nothing .

Comment: how to flash it with twrp recovery , i have recovery.img in sdcard and i click on install but it does not detect rom or img files.

Comment: Flash it with adb fastboot if isn't flash directly from sd card and normally there are four option in reboot of twrp 1.system 2.reboot 3.power off 4.fastboot and please mention your twrp version with kernal version of your phone and hold down the power button till it power off and  then connect to pc and flash rom with sp tool.

Comment: it was not booting and sp flash tool didnt work , and in fastboot mode no fastboot commands were working or on connecting it says waiting for device as it did not detect device.But how to use adb commands it only works when your device is opened.twrp 3.2.1.0 and kernel i dont know.

Comment: i didnt know kernel because it had gone for repair , now it is working.now i have 7.0 version and kernal is 3.18.35+

Comment: It may because your usb cable is damaged try to change it with another one and reinstall mtk drives may it will fix your problem.

Comment: tried it now i have a working phone and i went to the shop to repair.

Answer (score 0):

As You said when you installed TWRP on your Nokia 3. So, Its ovious Your phone can't boot into os. In TWRP Installation Guide Its Says "After Installing TWRP on your Phone your phone will not boot. it stuck in bootloop".

For this You Have to flash a file called "encrypt.zip" through TWRP to Your Phone. After This Your Phone again bootable to OS. and You don't need to Flash it. If you tried to Flash then, you are in big problem.

Thanks!